# How to aggregate by values represented in multiple columns with postgresql

Tags: sql, aggregate, greenplum

I am using postgresql 8.3.23
I have a table where an ip is represented into 3 different columns.
What is the best way to aggregate by IP and get sum by column without using multiple joins and multiple queries ?

table

| source | trans | dest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ip1 |  | ip2 |
| ip1 | ip1 | ip3 |
| ip1 | ip2 | ip3 |
| ip2 | ip4 | ip5 |

what I am trying to get

| ip | source | trans | dest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ip1 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| ip2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ip3 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| ip4 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| ip5 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Why are you using a version of Postgres that has not bee supported for over 7 years?

Comment: In short, this is a Greenplum database based on postgresql 8.3.23. 
A migration to a more decent version requires a full rebuild, which is challenging for a database containing 3.8 Petabytes of data

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot and re-aggregate:

```
select ip, sum(source), sum(trans), sum(dest)
from ((select source as ip, 1 as source, 0 as trans, 0 as dest
       from t
      ) union all
      (select trans as ip, 0 as source, 1 as trans, 0 as dest
       from t
      ) union all
      (select dest as ip, 0 as source, 0 as trans, 1 as dest
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by ip;
```

There are definitely different ways to express this logic.  But who remembers any more what Postgres 8.3 supported?

Comment: This query contains typos (2nd query is "select trans" as ip instead of "select source" etc ) but this is definitely the trick I was looking for, thanks.  I Will post the full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gordon's trick, I've ended with the below query. Since it's used to summarize 5.5 billion events ingested every day which some IP over-represented, getting the sum in the sub-queries turned out to be more efficient.

```
select ip, sum(source_count) as source_count, sum(trans_count) as trans_count, sum(dest_count) as dest_count
from ((select source as ip, count(*) as source_count, 0 as trans_count, 0 as dest_count
       from t where source is not null
       group by 1,3,4
      ) union all
      (select trans as ip, 0 as source_count, count(*) as trans_count, 0 as dest_count
       from t where trans is not null
       group by 1,2,4
      ) union all
      (select dest as ip, 0 as source_count, 0 as trans_count, count(*) as dest_count
       from t where dest is not null
       group by 1,2,3
      )
     ) t
group by ip
order by ip;
```